# Flutter - Dependant drop downs, changing one drop down value change the Second dropdown item option

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu

I am learning drop down in Flutter and was wondering if you could help me with dependant drop downs.

One drop will have one value but when i change that it should change the Second drop down value, below is an example of JSON -

```
List _nameList = [{
        "id": 1270,
        "name": "CHARLES",
        "option": [{
            "id": "72426",
            "number": "1085659"
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": 1353,
        "name": "HARRIS",
        "option": [{
                "id": "72605",
                "number": "1072236"
            },
            {
                "id": "72705",
                "number": "1082236"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Above, CHARLES and HARRIS should be in one drop down but if i change/select like CHARLES/HARRIS respected number should be auto selected into another drop down.

I am able to create one with value as CHARLES and HARRIS, below code -

```
DropdownButton(
    icon: Icon(
    CupertinoIcons.chevron_down,
    color: !roles.driver2
        ? Colors.grey[50]
        : AppColors.appColor,
    ),
    isExpanded: true,
    onChanged: onNameDropdownItem,
    items: _nameList,
    value: _selectedName,
    underline: SizedBox(),
    style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 18,
    color: Colors.black87,
    ),
)



onNameDropdownItem(Name selectedName) {
    int ind;
    _nameList.forEach((element) {
        if (selectedName.name == element.value.name)
        ind = _nameList.indexOf(element);
    });
    setState(() {
        _selectedName = _nameList[ind].value;
    });
}
```

Please help stuck here :(